# iOS autolayout visual format language translate

Tags: ios, autolayout, visual-format-language

I have the following constraint:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[drawerView(==tapView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]
```

I want to do some animation with it and therefore I need to have it parameterised. I want to have the same thing but using the API. This is what I tried but it doesn't work :

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:drawerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.drawerMenuVC.tapView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0]
```

What I want is to have both views have equal height.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Did you add this constraint to the superview of these two views?

Comment: Yes, just nothing happens.

Comment: You need also an height constraint on one of the view.

Comment: @GonjiDev thanks mate ! that really helped - you can write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another constraint like this and it should work:

```
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:drawerView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:yourHeightValue];
```